# Upgrading from beta to public release Yosemite incomplete?

Tags: macos

I was using the dev beta of Yosemite, when it was released to the public I updated, however I'm missing some components of Yosemite, I'm having trouble launching particular applications that make use of Yosemite 10.10 specific libraries as "DeveloperExtras" or WebKit2, something I noticed recently is also missing functionality on my settings, as the "Dark UI" mode which is supposed to be on System Preferences->General , This is quite strange as I have Yosemite version 10.10 installed, no update is required in the app store.

Guidance or any kind of suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you go to the Apple menu > About this Mac, then click on the version number (to get to the build number), what does it say? Mine is 14A388a.

Comment: Mine is 14A261i

Comment: Can you still download the installer from the App Store? If you can just run the whole thing it should work…